# What is wrong with this RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I want to have three images in one row, and a Video or two below them.
So far, I am unable to correctly position the three images via Relative Layout.

It gets quite different behaviour from what I expect it to be... it shows only one picture, as though it is a FrameLayout.I can assure you the images are in place. And the java code is nothing but straightforward OnCreate - super.OnCreate, setContentView(R.layout.component_name)  .
What is wrong with this relative layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/previous_frame"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/previous_frame" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/catch_frame"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/previous_frame" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/catch_frame"
         />
     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/next_frame" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/next_frame"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/catch_frame" 
    /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Aaah. Unbelievable. Was using toLeftOf instead toRight of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the code use android:toRightOf instead of android:toLeftOf..